# Laravel 5.4 NotificationSent vs MessageSending Events

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am a little confused about [MessageSending](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#events) and [NotificationSent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications#notification-events) events.
in my application, I want to save any notification and mail sent by the app inside a database Table.

for that, I created two event listeners **createNotificationLogOnSending** and **createNotificationLogOnSendingMessage**.

1) **createNotificationLogOnSending** is fired when success notification is sent which means **Illuminate\Notifications\Events\NotificationSent** event is fired by laravel notification system.

2) **createNotificationLogOnSendingMessage** is fired when **Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending** fired by laravel system.

the problem here, in the 2 use cases  **Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending** is fired which means **createNotificationLogOnSendingMessage** listener is listen to both **Illuminate\Notifications\Events\NotificationSent** and **Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending**

I want to make each listener fired for its event.

any solution for this problem or its laravel bug?